# C# - Open .RPD file (XML file in disguise), Save out as .XML and then open XML in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

As the header says - I am trying to Open a .RPD file (which is a XML file in disguise), Save out as .XML and then open XML using XmlDocument to process . . . all in c#.

This code below works until it hits the line string jN = jobName.InnerText; line.
The error I get is:-

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in XML Display.cs:line 73

Looks to me like it isn't picking up the new XML file correctly - even though it is there?

Can anybody point me in the right direction to get this to work?

```
// XML reading, writing and pulling out data.

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // set up some variables to use
        public string document;
        public string material;
        public string thickness;
        public string sheetx;
        public string sheety;
        public string used;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
        private void outputBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            // Filter for xml files only
            fDialog.Filter = "RPD File|*.rpd";
            // Filter for starting directory - in this case a network drive.
            fDialog.Title = "Please pick your RPD file . . .";

            if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                outputBox.AppendText("Converting your RPD into an XML, saving and then loading back in!" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                // set up xml document - using the filename used - load the XML
                XmlDocument thisOrder1 = new XmlDocument();
                string fN = fDialog.FileName;
                thisOrder1.Load(fN);
                int fileExtPos = fN.LastIndexOf(".");
                string nFN = fN.Substring(0, fileExtPos)+".xml";
                // make a duplicate of the file - rename it to a XML file
                System.IO.File.Copy(fN, nFN, true);
                XmlDocument thisOrder = new XmlDocument();
                // load up the new XML file.
                thisOrder.Load(nFN);

                outputBox.AppendText("Done!" + System.Environment.NewLine);

                // try and process this file
                try
                {
                    // pull in node list
                    XmlNodeList xmlnode = thisOrder.GetElementsByTagName("Sheet");
                    XmlNode jobName = thisOrder.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("JobName");

                    // pull jobName in from the XML
                    string jN = jobName.InnerText;
                    // replace question marks and extra spaces with nothing
                    jN = jN.Replace("?", "");
                    jN = jN.TrimEnd();
                    // outout the Job Name
                    outputBox.AppendText("Job Name > " + jN + System.Environment.NewLine);
                    // find the CR number from - this will have to be updated.
                    XmlNode crNumber = thisOrder.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("RadanSchedule/JobDetails/NestFolder");
                    string cR = crNumber.InnerText;
                    cR = cR.Substring(45, 8);

                    // output CR number and setup ready to show Material and amount used
                    outputBox.AppendText("CR Number > " + cR + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine);
                    outputBox.AppendText("Material\t\t\t\tUsed" + System.Environment.NewLine);

                    // main routine to pull out data as needed.
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
                        {
                            used = string.Format(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(11).InnerText);
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(used) >= 1)
                            {
                                material = string.Format(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText);
                                thickness = string.Format(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerText);
                                sheetx = string.Format(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(5).InnerText);
                                sheety = string.Format(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(6).InnerText);

                                outputBox.AppendText(material + "-" + thickness + "-" + sheetx + "-" + sheety + "\t\t\t" + used + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // if the data is found to be empty - tell us
                        outputBox.AppendText("No data found!" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // if there is a major problem - tell us
                    outputBox.AppendText("Problem processing new XML file!" + System.Environment.NewLine + "ERROR > " + ex + System.Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edited the code above to show **ALL** code.

Thank you.

Comment: Which line is line 73?

Comment: line 73 is the line the code here:-

string jN = jobName.InnerText;

Comment: Is the `JobName` node a direct child of the document element? Does `XmlNode jobName = thisOrder.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//JobName");` resolve it?

Comment: Coded amended to show ALL code. The error (now that) I have commented the code is on Line 61 - 'string jN = jobName.InnerText;'

Comment: Please post your XML.  The XML doesn't contain the tags you are looking for.  XML is case sensitive so make sure you properly have the upper/lower case letters correct.  You may also have issues if the tag name have a prefix (<prefix:tag>).

Comment: Thanks for the input so far. Unfortunately I can't post the XML as it contains private/delicate information. Sorry.

However - I have just tried something using notepad++
After opening the RPD file and then saving it out as a XML file - this works! All nodes are picked up without any errors.

Makes me think that the problem is when saving? Could the file still be open for writing so doesn't process properly?

Comment: This doesnt make any sense at all. `XMLDocument` does not give a hoot whether or not your document is named `.xml`. The whole copying process is nonsense. The rpd obviously **is** an xml file - which you load, do nothing with, then copy, then load in *another* `XMLDocument` object, then parse, then get the error. Did you read my earlier comment, and did you try my suggestion?

Comment: HI @LocEngineer - I did read your earlier comment and tried your suggestion too. Thank you for that - it still didn't work - I **think** I am missing something really obvious.

Comment: As I thought - the new file I had been given was slightly different to the test files. An extra line of text had been added in the main project file.

Sorry guys it is now working fine. Thank you for your time.